# Is it possible to call the as_view() method of class from the controller?

Tags: python, django, forms

I need to pass a variable that is initialized in the controller.

It looks like routing:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('form/check/', room_check, name='room_check'),
    path('contact/', BookWizard.as_view(FORMS, initial_dict=initial)),
]
```

Book Wizard - a class inherited from SessionWizardView from `formtools` module

The following is a piece of the controller where the variable is created:

```
initial = {
           '0': {'check_in_date': check_in_date,
                 'date_of_eviction': date_of_eviction,
                 'category': category,
                 'number_of_adults': number_of_adults,
                 'number_of_children': number_of_children}}

return redirect(BookWizard.as_view(FORMS, initial_dict=initial))
```

As a result, I get this error:
[image: error]

Maybe there is another way to pass the variable and call the method, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, since it aims to find the same function. A function is equal based on *reference* equality. But here you construct two functions that might *do* the same, but are still two different objects.

That being said, you do not need this, and it is also rather "inelegant" to do so. More Pythonic is to give the view a name, and refer to the name:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('form/check/', room_check, name='room_check'),
    path('contact/', BookWizard.as_view(FORMS, initial_dict=initial), name='contact'),
]
```

and in your view refer to it with:

```
return redirect('contact')
```

Note that you can not "pass parameters" in a redirect call other than the one encoded in the URL, or in cookies or session variables. So the `initial` will be the one you have set in the `urlpatterns`, regardless what the `initial` is you set in the `redirect`.

Comment: That is, there are no other ways to transfer data?
Sorry if I misunderstood. I'm still learning english :(

Comment: @elVladosios: a `redirect` is just a HTTP response, it says to the browser "*Hey you should visit this url "...."*". The browser then visits that URL (if the browser allows that). Your webserver thus retrieves a new request, and all requests in a (proper) webserver are isolated. So you need to *encode* data you need in the URL, in the cookies that the browser will send in the next request, or store it in the database (in such a way that your next request can retrieve that). So no, you need to encode the data in a form such that the browser can "propagate" it to the next request.

Comment: Good. Thank you so much!